# How to show the link preview in Whatsapp and twitter(and likewise apps) when I pass a URL link from my own app?

Tags: android, twitter, hyperlink, preview

I want to share a link through my app and I can easily do it with the help of intents. My problem is that when someone tries to forward that link through Whatsapp or Twitter or other apps it does not show the link preview to that URL. How can this functionality be achieved?

Comment: fwiw slack can handle this if you approve, I just don't know the details